# Google App Deploy Operation timed out error

Tags: deployment, cloud, gcloud

I had deployed my application on the google cloud successfully, tested it and it is running fine.

Now I wanted to push some changes to the code so I tried to push my revised code and used the command: `gcloud app deploy` to deploy my updated codebase. However I am getting the following error:

> Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
>   ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Operation
>   [apps/*******/*******/d756b4f7-d9a8-48c8-b6dc-1d87889a18bf] timed out.
>   This operation may still be underway.

Earlier I was getting the error health check timeout, so I increased the accepted time out time to be max, 3600 after which I am getting the above mentioned error.